# Find a closed simply-connected $4$-manifold with closed non-exact $2$-form

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, closed-form, differential-forms, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a closed simply-connected smooth $4$-manifold with a closed non-exact 2-form on it. $H^2_{dR}(M) \ne 0$.

By de Rham theorem, $H_{dR}^2(M) \cong H^2(M;\mathbb R) \cong \text{Hom}(H_2(M;\Bbb Z),\Bbb R)$.

Let $M = S^2 \times S^2$ with coordinates $((\theta_1,\varphi_1), (\theta_2,\varphi_2))$, how can we find such closed but non-exact form on it?

**Edit:**

How can we find such $2$-form explicity in coordinates $((\theta_1,\varphi_1), (\theta_2,\varphi_2))$?

Comment: Caffeine's answer gives you an easy answer to your edit. This is the area $2$-form on $S^2$, which you can easily write down in spherical coordinates. In American notation, it's $\sin\phi\,d\phi\wedge d\theta$; in European notation,  switch $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a closed non exact 2-form on $S^2$. Let $\pi:S^2\times S^2\to S^2$
be the usual projection on the first factor.
Define $\hat \omega$ as the pullback of $\omega$ through $\pi$.
$\hat\omega$ is closed, since $d(\pi^*\omega)=\pi^*(d\omega)=0$.
It is not exact, since its restriction to the embedded submanifold $S^2\times \{(0,0,1)\}\simeq S^2$ is not exact.

To find an explicit example, take $\omega=\iota^*(xdy\wedge dz-ydx\wedge dz+z dx\wedge dy)$,
where $\iota$ is the inclusion of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Another way to show that the form is not exact is to integrate it over $S^2$, for example in spherical coordinates. The result is non-zero and Stokes' theorem tells you that the form can't be exact.

Comment: Related: [Closed not exact form on $\Bbb R^n∖{0}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286162)